# Forced override of parent class method PHP

Tags: php, class, inheritance, interface

I have a situation that, despite a fair amount of googling/SO'ing, seems to escape me. Here's the issue in a nutshell:

### Situation

PHP 5.3+ (but not specific yet - I'm actually running 5.5/6 but the environment is aiming to be flexible).

I'm attempting to write a solid implementation that will force other developers into best practice.

I have a parent class:

```
class A {
    public function doSomething() {
        // does something
    }
}
```

The standard use case is to use `A::doSomething`.

In special cases, an extension is required.

```
class B extends A {
    public function doSomething() {
        // does something .. AND
        $this->doSomethingElse()
    }

    private function doSomethingElse() {
        // does something else
    }
}
```

If I want to *do something*, then I can `A::doSomething`.
If I want to *do something and do something else*, then I can `B::doSomething`.

In order to fit the remit of *forc[ing] other developers into best practice*, I have implemented an interface:

```
interface C {

    public function doSomething() {
        // does something else
    }

    public function doSomethingElse() {
        // does something else
    }
}
```

Class B then implements Interface C. Sounds simple enough?

```
class B implements C {
    public function doSomething() {
        // does something .. AND
        $this->doSomethingElse()
    }

    private function doSomethingElse() {
        // does something else
    }
}
```

I don't want to assume that the child `B` implements `C`.
There could be a number of completely valid reasons to extend `A` to `E`, where `E` does not want to implement `C`.

### My actual question:

If I do the following, and don't implement the `doSomething` method, the following has no errors:

```
class B implements C {
    private function doSomethingElse() {
        // does something else
    }
}
```

.. which is as you'd expect; `A` provides `doSomething` for `B` to satisfy the requirement for `C`.

The issue is that this would allow someone to write an incomplete method that would fail to throw errors. In the above case `B::doSomething` does not call `B::doSomethingElse`.

Is it possible for a method, interface (or similar technique) to **require** a child to implement a method *at the current inheritance level*?

Of course I can write notes, documentation etc... but the point of the interface is to make people do it correctly!

Other people who've asked similar questions were either (sometimes understandibly) misunderstood *or* the stock answer was "the architecture is wrong"... Which I'd like to challenge as the example below illustrates:

Here's an example with real world items:

- A = Shop item for sale : ShopItem
- B = Shop item of type "Beer" : Beer
- C = BoozeInterface : Interface that .. say triggers ID requirements
- D = Shop item of type "Vegetables" : Vegetable

A might have a method called, say... `A::attemptToBuy`
`C` would enforce methods like ID required.

`Beer` and `Vegetable` are both a type of ShopItem.
This is a standard and logical inheritance.

`Beer` needs to use `BoozeInterface` (or whatever is appropriate). This would also be true of the not yet implement, but possibly future requirement of `Wine`, `Spirit` etc etc.

Some items fit perfectly in to a generic `ShopItem` class. They need no extra functionality.
`ShopItem::attemptToBuy` is a normal use case.

However - I have to rely on someone remembering to override the `Wine::attemptToBuy` and `Spirit::attemptToBuy`.

As you can see - if I want to *really* lock it down, I'd ideally be able to force an override at the current level of inheritance.
(I'm sure there are better examples of this, but I've tried to make it as obvious as possible).

I'm happy if the answer is "no, you can't do that"... I just want to know if you can. I have the code working, but just via a direct override that is unforced. But I want it to be forced!

Thanks in advance.
Rick

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding what you want to do, but how about [abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)?

Comment: Abstraction has the same issue. It accepts its parent classes methods.

Comment: You say in a couple of places that `B` is an child class but the code doesn't show that and this is confusing. Please fix the code samples.

Comment: Extend Edits - Done.

Comment: Couldn't you just test is `doSomethingElse` is callable in `A::doSomething`? If yes, call it there... and all the children classes will automatically have their `doSomethingElse` method called without the need to redefine `doSomething`.

Comment: @RickMorice I have a possible solution combining interface and abstraction, but before I write it out, I wanted to clarify - do you want Class A not to require both interface methods?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the intent here but I agree that abstraction is probably the way to go, just tinkering about here but is this the kind of thing you're after? : http://codepad.org/feG74YVL

Comment: *"... which is as you'd expect; A provides doSomething for B to satisfy the requirement for C."* Class `A` must not be aware of class `B` and interface `C`. `B` depends on `A` and `C`, `A` and `C` must not depend on anything else.

Comment: axiac - It doesn't. A doesn't need to be aware of B or C. You're over complicating it.
Interface C is simply saying that "if you implement me" you must implement feature X at the current level of inheritance. Can this be done... that's the question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make class A abstract and require those methods that way:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract protected function doSomething() {}
    abstract protected function doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

Now any class that extends class A must define those two methods.

Cheers!

Comment: That does exactly what was asked :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is "another way of doing it", not an answer to the question. While I'm not saying that it's a bad approach, it's not what I asked. Like I said - there are probably other ways to do it - my question was specific.
Class A is not abstract, and A::doSomething is in use...
Sure I could make A(1) extend A(abstract), but that wasn't the question.
Cheers tho.

Comment: Indeed Abstract class is the best approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about it backwards - I'm not sure you want to enforce an override (easily done with abstract methods) in the client-developer created sub-classes, you want to provide a method that **cannot** be overridden in your provided abstract classes to ensure it does what you want it to?

If you provide the abstract classes `ShopItem` and `BoozeItem` thus:

```
<?php

// base ShopItem with default `attemptToBuy` functionality
abstract class ShopItem {

    public function attemptToBuy() {
        echo "buying ShopItem";
    }
}

// Booze sub-class, with an override on `attemptToBuy` 
// (e.g. applying age restrictions check)
abstract class BoozeItem extends ShopItem {

    final public function attemptToBuy() {
        echo "buying BoozeItem";
    }
}

?>
```

The client developer can then happily create their `Beer` class extending the `BoozeItem` sub-class.

```
<?php

class Beer extends BoozeItem { }

$oBevvy = new Beer();
$oBevvy->attemptToBuy();

?>
```

Outputs: *buying BoozeItem*

Since `BoozeItem::attemptToBuy()` has been declared `final` it can't be overridden by `Booze::attemptToBuy()` (trying to create that method will cause an error) - so your object functionality is locked down.

`Beer` can be extended to `Lager` or `Ale` (for instance) and those will inherit `attemptToBuy()` from `BoozeItem` (since `Beer` extends `BoozeItem`) **but** they won't be allowed to override that method as it's declared `final` - it'll simply be inherited with the defined behavior. This isn't what you want but it's probably the closest you'll get I think.

Comment: See - It's likely I do want to override it. The shop example is just an example... but in that case, Beer could be extended to Lager/Bitter etc. 
Also - as I said in response to versalle88's answer - this is another way of doing it, not an answer to "can you force overriding".
Thanks for an interesting suggestion tho, I'll review it and think about things.

Comment: @RickMorice - I *think* the only way you can enforce an override is to declare the method abstract in a parent abstract class... however, that's not exactly an override since the initial abstract method will have no default behavior. Abstract methods, or indeed Interfaces, are simply ways of declaring that certain class methods **must** exist - not what they do. In your example Class `B` would fail when attempting to implement Interface `C` since you can't declare `doSomethingElse()` to be private when it's defined in the Interface - that's not what Interfaces are for.

Comment: This sidesteps the problem - interface or none, I want to know if it's possible to inherit from a non-abstract parent class and enforce an override.
I would assume that this is interface territory (hence me using them in an example). PHP manual states: "Object interfaces allow you to create code which specifies which methods a class must implement, without having to define how these methods are handled." I want to specify a mandatory override.
Like I said in the question, the answer may just be "no you can't" which is fine. The code works, it's the behaviour I want to enforce I'm asking about.

Comment: @RickMorice - I'm pretty sure the short answer is *that you can't do it in the way you want to* ;) You either have a parent method, with a default behavior, that **can** be overridden completely or you have an abstract (or Interface) method that has no default behavior. The only way you could have a sub-class execute the parent's behavior as part of the override is by calling it within the child method (as you'd do when calling the parent constructor: `parent::__construct()`) - but again, that's not exactly what you're after.